# How come while (myNode.lastElementChild) works without any value?

Tags: javascript, loops

Im learning JS by analyzing a to-do list tutorial and I'm stuck trying to fully understand the functions that clears a populated list by clicking a button.
I think I understand this small script but not sure.

```
    `function clearTaks(){
        while(taskList.firstChild){
            taskList.removeChild(taskList.firstChild);
        }`
```

I think that the condition **while(taskList.firstChild)** means that meanwhile taskList still has a Chidren, keep doing... but I wonder why that works without any other value. I mean, shouldn´t it be something like this?: **while(taskList.firstChild != false)** or something similar.
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`taskList.firstChild` is coerced to a boolean.

`firstChild` will return `null` if there is no child, which is [Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) (thus you will get `false` and the loop will terminate).